# iOS: Displaying views of other viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

So if there is a UIScrollView which should display a number of different views I'm used to creating them as different view controllers, and hooking them up in IB.

After I import them in the main view controller I **add the views of the separate view controllers** onto the scrollview as a subview.

**Is this a good (safe) approach?**

If the main view controller (owner of the scrollview) deallocates **will it take care of the other instantiated viewcontrollers** whose views are displayed in the scrollview?

**Or should I call nil** on all the separate VCs in the main VC's dealloc or viewDidDisappear?

Comment: So you have a MainViewController, in it is a UIScrollView and you want to load different UIViewController(loaded from a NIB) into the UIScrollView?

Comment: If you have ARC enabled, you are good to go. If not, instantiate your UIViewControllers in your MainViewController, add them as subview to your UIScrollView and after adding them as subview, just release the viewcontroller you just instantiated from nib.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. With ARC it is a good pattern to nil all (strong) references in the dealloc method of a view controller, but afaik it is not really required. It does not really matter if it is a strong reference to another view controller or to a view or to any memory consuming object.